# How to pass http response data from service to app.module.ts

Tags: angular

I made a service that calls some api keys from backend to config my app globally in `app.module.ts`. The service called data including even before app init, but I don't know how to pass into `app.module.ts`. Anyone ever faced this situation?

global-settings.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalSettingsService {

  apiUrl: any;

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    @Inject(ORIGIN_URL) private baseUrl: string,
    @Inject(API_PREFIX) private apiPrefix: string
  ) {
    this.apiUrl = this.baseUrl + this.apiPrefix;
   }

  load() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http
            .get(this.apiUrl + 'bootstrap')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response);
                resolve(true);
            });
    });
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
export function getUserAuthServiceConfigs() {
  const config = new AuthServiceConfig(
    [
      {
        id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(// I WANT TO PASS DATA FROM THE SERVICE ABOVE HERE //)
      },
    ]
  );
  return config;
}

export function globalSettingsProviderFactory(provider: GlobalSettingsService) {
  return (data) => provider.load();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    GlobalSettingsService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: globalSettingsProviderFactory, deps: [GlobalSettingsService], multi: true },
    { provide: AuthServiceConfig, useFactory: getUserAuthServiceConfigs },
    { provide: ORIGIN_URL, useValue: '/' },
    { provide: API_PREFIX, useValue: 'api/' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is how the reponse in console returned before the app init:

```
{
    googleClientId: "abcd"
    reCaptchaKey: "efgh"
}
```

Comment: `The service called data including even before app init`? what does it mean Your service is called before your application is up?

Comment: Before this console `Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.`, the response data was already in the console. If you don't know this, have a look here: https://devblog.dymel.pl/2017/10/17/angular-preload/